# Database retrieval system

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have made this site for a school project and it doesn't seem to be retrieving the data. I have been going over it for AGES and cannot find out why it is not retrieving.  the SQL sometimes works in phpMyAdmin but never works in the interface.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","#","book_catalogue");

{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-col">
        <img src="images/left-img.png" alt="books" />
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>BOOK CATALOGUE</h1>
    </div>

    <!--Radio buttons that allow user to select the search criteria-->
    <div id="navigation">
        <form name="input" action="indexV4.php" method="get">
                SEARCH BY: ALL<input type="radio" name="books" value="ALL" checked>
                TITLE<input type="radio" name="books" value="TITLE">
                AUTHOR<input type="radio" name="books" value="AUTHOR">
                GENRE<input type="radio" name="books" value="GENRE">
                BOOK TYPE<input type="radio" name="books" value="BOOKTYPE"> 
                <input type="text" name="SEARCH" value="SEARCH">
                <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>
    </div>
            <?php
            $Books = $_GET['books'];
            $Search = $_GET['SEARCH'];
                //if the radio button 'TITLE' is selected, this query will run
                if($Books=='TITLE')
                    {
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,"
                        SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
                        WHERE tbl_books.Title LIKE '%$Search%'");
                    }
                    //if the radio button 'AUTHOR' is selected, this query will run
                else if ($Books=='AUTHOR')
                    {
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,"
                        SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories
                        WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
                        WHERE tbl_books.Author LIKE '%$Search%'");
                    }
                    //if the radio button 'GENRE' is selected, this query will run
                else if ($Books=='GENRE')
                    {
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,"
                        SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, tbl_books.Type_id, tbl_books.Category_id FROM tbl_books
                        WHERE tbl_books.Author LIKE '%$Search%'");
                    }
                    //if the radio button 'BOOK TYPE' is selected, this query will run
                else if ($Books=='BOOKTYPE')
                    {
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,"
                        SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories 
                        WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
                        WHERE tbl_book_type.Name LIKE '%$Search%'");
                    }
                    //if 'ALL' is selected, this query will run
                else 
                {
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "
                    SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
                    WHERE tbl_books.Title OR tbl_books.Author OR tbl_categories.Name OR tbl_book_type.Name LIKE '%$Search%'");
                }
            //while it is retrieving the data, echo it onto the screen
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
     {
            ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <!--Display of search results-->

        <div class="books">
            <img src="book-covers/<?php echo $row['Book_Image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" />
            <p class="first"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['Author']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['ISBN']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['Type_id']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['Category_id']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    //close the loop
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **What does "doesn't seem to be retrieving the data" mean?**  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Whenever i load the page this statement comes up:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\book_catalogue\indexV4.php on line 82

Comment: Perhaps you should look for a '{' on line 82.

Comment: Lesson #1 when asking for help: **If you get an error message, then you must include the error message with your request for help.**  That is the single most useful tool for anyone trying to help debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect to begin with. You cannot have two WHERE in a single statement. The following is one of your query statement

```
SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, 
       tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, 
       tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name 
FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories
WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND 
      (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
WHERE tbl_books.Title LIKE '%$Search%'
```

Do you see you use `WHERE` two times?

---

Additionally, your code is not secure. You should use PDO or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Yes i see i have WHERE twice but i couldn't think of anything else to see if it would work.  And could you please explain why it is not secure, i am a high school student and haven't learnt any of this before

Answer (score 0):

As invisal said, you cannot have 2 WHERE in one statement.

I suggest changing your if statement contents. Instead of `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT BLA BLA");`

Do this:

$sql = "SELECT BLA BLA";

Then, AFTER the if statements create the $sql, do this:

```
$result = mysql_query($con,$sql);

if($result === false) {
  echo 'Error in query [' . $sql . ']' . "\n" . 'Error: ' . mysql_error();
}
```

Then you'll see what's wrong with your queries.

EDIT:
Let me try to make this clearer:

```
if($Books=='TITLE')
                    {
                        $sql = "SELECT tbl_books.ISBN, tbl_books.Title, tbl_books.Author, tbl_books.Book_Image, tbl_book_type.Name, tbl_categories.Name FROM tbl_books, tbl_book_type, tbl_categories WHERE (tbl_books.Type_id = tbl_book_type.Type_id) AND (tbl_books.Category_id = tbl_categories.Category_id)
                        WHERE tbl_books.Title LIKE '%$Search%'";
                    }
```

Change ALL of your if/else if statements to look like that. What you are doing is using the if statements to decide which query will be contained by the variable `$sql`;

Then, AFTER all of the if statements, you can send the `$sql` query as I've shown above. If there is a mistake in your query, the `if($result === false)` section will output mysql's complaint to your screen, and that should help you debug your query.

Comment: What would changing $con to $sql do?  As i said to invisal i am only a high school student so you might have to dumb some of the stuff down and then maybe then some